# VScode and CLion debug mode remains pending and does nothing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, clion, wsl-2

I have a problem at launching VScode in debug mode.
Same exact problem with JetBrains CLion.

I am using Windows 11 and WSL to debug a C++ application. It does contain debug symbols, I can use GDB from the WSL command line with no problems. I can also debug "Hello, World!" from both VScode and CLion with no problem.

When I launch my application in debug mode, VScode remains pending for some minutes and then gives the following error from the VScode Debug console

```
ERROR: GDB exited unexpectedly. Debugging will now abort.
The program '/path/to/executable/executableWithDebugSymbols' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

and the following error from the VScode terminal

```
Killed
[1] + Killed                     "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-sn05zyct.ioa" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-uesxpqcr.3at"
```

So I tried to launch GDB from the WSL command line with the same VScode arguments, that is `"/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-sn05zyct.ioa" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-uesxpqcr.3at"`.

So the third argument `0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-sn05zyct.zsy"` is giving me a non-existent file/folder error, so I simply get rid of it. Then I launched

```
/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-uesxpqcr.pad
```

And I have found that the problematic argument is exactly `1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-uesxpqcr.pad`. Note that I have been in touch with the JetBrains support, and they told me that CLion has the same exact problem with writing files in the `/tmp` folder.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

---

Edit

The output of `ls -ld /tmp` gives

```
drwxrwxrwt 5 root root 61440 Aug 10 12:26 /tmp
```

while the output of `ls -ld /tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-0gkeomgi.crh` (I had to re-run VScode as I deleted the content of `/tmp/` after posting this question and so `/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-uesxpqcr.pad` too) is:

```
prw------- 1 myUsername myUsername 0 Aug 10 13:12 /tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-0gkeomgi.crh
```

---

Edit 2

I changed the default temporary folder from `/tmp/` to `TMPDIR=~/my_debug_tmp`, get the same errors.

Comment: Have you checked permissions on the `/tmp` folder? And on the file `/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-uesxpqcr.pad` (if it exists).

Comment: I do not know how to check permission on the `/tmp/` folder except launching everything with Run as Administrator mode. But, I can access `/tmp/` and do things in it from the WSL command line. Do you have any suggestions?

Concerning `/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-uesxpqcr.pad`, this file s created by VScode in the `/tmp/` folder, so it existed when I launched afterwards GDB from the WSL command line.

Comment: From the WSL console execute the command `ls -ld /tmp` and the command `ls -ld /tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-uesxpqcr.pad` and add the output of those commands to the question above.

Comment: Find them on the main post

Comment: OK, well it doesn't seem to be a permissions issue. I'm afraid I don't have any further ideas.